Error Ubuntu Boot freezing after "Begin: Running /scripts/local-bottom ... done,"
I have a server Ubuntu 22.04 and after I reboot my server, it gets stuck at this screen for about 20 minutes.

[    4.354433] ioc3: LSI53C1030 BO: Capabilities={Initiator}
[    4.595047] scsi host5: ioc3: LSI53C1030 BO, FwRev=01032920h, Ports=1, MaxQ=128, IRQ=16
Begin: Loading essential drivers
[    5.198200] raid6: avx2x4 gen() 18713 MB/s
[    5.266189] raid6: avx2x4 5.334181] raid6: avx2x2 gen() 18595 MB/s
xor() 7777 MB/s
[    5.402204] raid6: avx2x2 xor() 17148 MB/s
[    5.470190] raid6: avx2x1 gen() 13839 MB/s
[    5.538195] raid6: avx2x1 xor() 7899 MB/s
[    5.606188] raid6: sse2x4 gen() 9892 MB/s
[    5.674188] raid6: sse2x4 
[    5.742184] raid6: sse2x2 gen() 11873 MB/s xor() 6198 MB/s
[    5.810192] raid6: sse2x2 5.878184] raid6: sse2x1 xor() gen() 7279 MB/s 9925 MB/s
[    5.946180] raid6: sse2x1 xor() 5192 MB/s
[    5.946582] raid6: using algorithm avx2x4 gen() 18713 MB/s 
[    5.946928] raid6: .... xor() 7777 MB/s, rmw enabled
[    5.947267] raid6: using avx2x2 recovery algorithm
[    5.948781] xor: automatically using best checksumming function avx
[    5.950433] async_tx: api initialized (async)
done.
Begin: Running/scripts/init-premount ... done.
Begin: Mounting root file system Begin: Running/scripts/local-top... done.
Begin: Running/scripts/local-premount .. 
[    6.086682] Btrfs loaded, crc32c=crc32c-intel, zoned=yes, fsverity=yes
Scanning for Btrfs filesystems
done.
Begin: Will now check root file system... fsck from util-linux 2.37.2
[/usr/sbin/fsck.ext4 (1) /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv] fsck.ext4 -a -CO 
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--g-ubuntu--1v
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv: clean, 148574/2555904 files, 9140617/10222592 blocks
done.
[    6.241698] EXT4-fs (dm-3): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null). Quota mode:
done.
done.
Begin: Running/scripts/local-bottom ... done. 
Begin: Running/scripts/init-bottom... done.

